# Second ansible role not running in playbook

Tags: ansible, roles

I am experimenting with using roles in a playbook.  My simple playbook is as follows:

```
---
  - name: Simple playbook
    hosts: all
    tasks:
    - name: Role1
      include_role:
        name: role1
      vars:
        debugmode : true
    - name: Role2
      include_role:
        name: role2
      vars:
        debugmode : true
```

I run the playbook with -vvv and I see all of my role1 tasks run.  However, role2 tasks don't run, I just see this output (excerpt):

```
TASK [Role2] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /myplaybook.yml:10
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers
```

my my role2/tasks/main.yml file is:

```
  - debug:
    msg: "In create_vms role"
```

Comment: Tried the same scenario locally but didn't face any problems. But had the same output when I commented the debug task in role2, just wanted to let you know.

Comment: Indentation wouldn't be a problem if you indent tasks at the same level. The problem here seems to be that role2 doesnt load its main.yml and that is strange. Can you try calling it with 'tasks_from: main' just under the name:role2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the cause of the problem is rather silly, I suspect this may help someone else.

The problem was that my file was accidentally named

> role2/tasks/mail.yml

(not main.yml).

So ansible had no problem with this, it just ignored the file and did nothing.  Seems like ansible should raise some kind of warning if no files are found in a role, so check for a typo :)